# How to cut a small amount into object?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a poker chip with Blender.

It would look like this at the end https://www.artstation.com/artwork/rGeB2 The little disks without the color.

[image]

This what I have:

[image: I want to cut the orange part in a little on both the upside and downside of the object]

I want to cut the orange part in a little on both the upside and downside of the object. When I tried doing this by scaling the z-axes down it pulled in the sides of the object as well.

All I want is the orange part to be indented in.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you are trying to do. I don't really understand what you are trying do to

Comment: I updated my post again.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a circle; Extrude + scale it **outside**; Make inner rim an edge loop and extrude it along Z; Fill the inside and use Poke Faces on it; Extrude the outside rim like 0.01 more than the inner one; Select all and use Mirror modifier on it; Give the model materials.[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you got what I meant. It would look like this at the endhttps://www.artstation.com/artwork/rGeB2 The little disks without the color.

Comment: Is it o.k. now ? If not, just attach the image of the object you want to model.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling in Z, or any transform of the selected region, will move the vertices shared by the region and the outer rim. Somehow, new vertices must be created on the perimeter of the region which can move independently of the ones on the rim, and new faces created between the region and the rim.

- Typically you would do this by <kbd>E</kbd> extruding the selected region of faces, and moving the mouse. By default, that will be by translating along the average normal of the region (here, global Z).
- But getting the sides to move toward one another by the same amount would be a scale. The Blender way is to use  <kbd>E</kbd> as before, *cancel* the subsequent move of the (now independent) faces by right-clicking, and *then*, with the faces still selected by the operation,  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> scale them toward one another.

Right-clicking after an extrude does *not* cancel the creation of new faces. It just cancels the move. Without any kind of move , the new faces are still there, hidden. This is a very common cause of errors, so you have to look out for it.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> cancels the extrude.